# Regex How to obfuscate values beetween =' '?

Tags: java, regex

There is string like that
 `Java='ffyfufu', Java=123`

Task: to transcribe the values by ****, i.e. the final string should be `Java='*****', Java=*****`

There is regular expression `(?<=Java[=:]'?).*?[^',]+`

I need to consider 2 cases with =' and without =

But I get `Java=*****', Java=*****` (without ')

Actual result

```
Java=*****', Java=*****
```

Expected result

```
Java='*****', Java=*****
```

Why it not work? And Help please how I can consider 2 cases?

Thanks

Comment: Please give us a complete [mcve], it would only take a few lines to show all of this. And note, your capture group in the regex includes the ' quote char. So maybe you aren't printing what you captured? But we dont know, because you only gave us fragments of your code. Give us all of the relevant code please!

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `.*?` part as the dot matches any character.

```
(?<=Java[=:]'?)[^',]+
```

- `(?<=Java[=:]'?)` Positive lookbehind, assert Java, `=` or `:` to the left and an optional `'`
- `[^',]+` Match 1+ chars other than `'` `,`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yg35Jj/1)

```
String regex = "(?<=Java[=:]'?)[^',]+";
String string = "Java='ffyfufu', Java=123";
System.out.println(string.replaceAll(regex, "*****"));
```

Output

```
Java='*****', Java=*****
```

---

If you want to match the individual characters, another option could be:

```
(?<=Java[=:]'?[^']{0,100})[^',]
```

In the replacement use a single `*`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kYNnUI/1)

Comment: @user16320675 In that case you can omit the comma from `[^',]`

Comment: @user16320675 That depends on if those are values that can actually occur in the OP's data. There could possible also be `Java="notok"` or `Java='no\'tok'`or `Java="no\"tokJava=test'"`

Comment: @Thefourthbird  I really liked your second - (?<=Java[=:]'?[^']{0,100})[^',] - idea

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```java
(?<=Java[=:])(?:(')[^']*(')|\S+)
```

Replace with `$1*****$2`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sJk6l2/1).

*Details*:

- `(?<=Java[=:])` - a location immediately preceded with `Java=` or `Java:`
- `(?:(')[^']*(')|\S+)` - either of

  - `(')[^']*(')` - `'` (Group 1), zero or more chars other than `'`, and then a `'` (captured into Group 2)
  - `|` - or
  - `\S+` - one or more non-whitespace chars.

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/MjUJeu):

```java
String s = " Java='f fyf ufu', Java=123";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?<=Java[=:])(?:(')[^']*(')|\\S+)", "$1*****$2"));
```

Output:

```
Java='*****', Java=*****
```